# Prevent Button Flicker When Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

When you hover over my image, a button will appear. The problem is that when the user tries to click on the button it starts to flicker the user is now off the `<img>` tag. I cannot place the jQuery `hover()` selector to detect when the user is hovering over my entire item as I have text under the image and I do not want the button to appear when the user is hovering over the text. How would I get the `<button>` to not flicker when the user tries to click it.

http://jsfiddle.net/DEQkk/

```
​<div class="item">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x100">
  <button>More Info</button>
  <p>Description</p>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

​button { position:absolute; top:20px; left:90px; display:none; }​

​$('.item img').hover( function() {
        $(this).parent().find('button').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).parent().find('button').hide();
    }
);​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the hover effect to the image and the button:

```
$('.item img, .item button').hover( function() {
        $(this).parent().find('button').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).parent().find('button').hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: This works, but you would be wasting processing time because the event handlers would be executed twice.

Comment: Cool, didn't know you can target multiple elements with the jQuery selector :)

Answer (score 2):

It flickers because when the mouse enters, or hovers over the button, it leaves the image. To fix it, move the event handler to the `<div>`:

```
$('.item div').hover( function() {
        $(this).find('button').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('button').hide();
    }
);​
```

[Working Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DEQkk/9/)

**Edit:** Place a `<div>` inside of your `.item` with the image and the button wrapped inside of it, as such:

```
<div class="item">
   <div>
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x100">
      <button>More Info</button>
   </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: I can't move it to the `<div>` as I don't want `hover()` to be applied when the user hovers over the text.

Comment: Simple solution. Silly me didn't think to add an extra div.